# Switching from Mac OSX Lion Theme back to 12.04 easily

Tags: 12.04, themes, acer, mac

So I was thinking about installing a Mac OSX Lion theme onto my ubuntu 12.04 computer (just for fun). I have never installed a theme before but I have watched videos and know in general how it is done but one question still remains.

After installing Mac OSX Lion theme (for example) can I easily and quickly switch back to my previous 12.04 settings? Then am I able to jump back and forth at a few clicks of the mouse?

Basicly I am just wondering after everything is set up can I switch my computer from looking like OSX to 12.04 at my  leisure or do I always have you change all of my settings?

Thanks.

Comment: You can just reset Unity settings to its default - http://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've already downloaded the appropriate Mac OSX theme components (wallpapers, cursors, icons, window theme), it's easy enough to switch between themes using the gnome-tweak-tool. However, it's not a one-click procedure.

Noobs Lab has a [good tutorial](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/05/mac-os-x-lion-for-ubuntu-1204-precise.html) for installing and setting up a Mac theme. The tutorial includes installing gnome-tweak-tool, and a couple other apps that assist in "Macifying" your interface.

Don't hesitate to ask follow-up questions if any of the theme-installation steps need clarification.

Comment: Thank you Alex i honestly have yet to install any themes (waiting for a rainy day) I will try this walk through and if i have any other questions I make sure to ask thank you.